How do I create array for sequence of months between 2 dates?
I have 2 columns; start date and end date and I'd like to create the sequence of months between the two dates.
I can do this using formula and then copying the formula through the whole column
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SEQUENCE(1,MONTH(B2)-MONTH(A2)+1,MONTH(A2),1))

However, I'd like this to be created as an array. I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:
=BYROW(A2:B4,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SEQUENCE(1,MONTH(CHOOSECOLS(a,2))-MONTH(CHOOSECOLS(a,1))+1,MONTH(CHOOSECOLS(a,1)),1))))

What am I doing wrong here?


What is your expected output for [Start Date]='01/11/2023' and [End Date]='31/03/2024'?

Hey @Chronocidal why don't you post an answer? For the query you put up to the OP?

@MayukhBhattacharya I had not posted an answer for it partly because, depending on Use Case, OP might want 11,12,1,2,3; or OP might require 11,12,13,14,15.  It all depends on how they are using the data, and how that impacts roll-over of years.  Hence why I initially just requested clarification

Try using the following formula:


=BYROW(MONTH(A2:B4),LAMBDA(α, LET(δ, INDEX(α,1), TEXTJOIN(",",,SEQUENCE(INDEX(α,2)-δ+1,,δ)))))


Edit: Using CHOOSECOLS() is also possible, only that its an array function, you would need to use the implicit intersection operator to make Excel realize that custom LAMBDA() had to be applied per row, while using INDEX() it does not require as it takes the row reference for the cols. Also using @ it needs one extra keying while the INDEX() doesn't!


=BYROW(MONTH(A2:B4),LAMBDA(α,
 LET(δ,@CHOOSECOLS(α,1),TEXTJOIN(",",,
 SEQUENCE(@CHOOSECOLS(α,2)-δ+1,,δ)))))


Addendum: if you have got older dates which are not in the same year, then the above will certainly return an error, therefore use the following:


• Using INDEX():
=BYROW(A6:B12,LAMBDA(α, LET(δ, INDEX(α,1), 
 TEXTJOIN(",",,MONTH(UNIQUE(TEXT(SEQUENCE(INDEX(α,2)-δ+1,,δ),"mmm e")))))))


• Using CHOOSECOLS():
=BYROW(A6:B12,LAMBDA(α, LET(δ, @CHOOSECOLS(α,1), 
TEXTJOIN(",",,MONTH(UNIQUE(TEXT(SEQUENCE(@CHOOSECOLS(α,2)-δ+1,,δ),"mmm e")))))))



Workaround by forcing to be single (value)
I haven't fully understood it yet, but when using CHOOSECOLS, TAKE etc. with some functions such as SEQUENCE, TEXTJOIN etc. treat the input as columns, and return only the first column. The easiest workaround seems to be to convert the parameter to a single value. For example, in your case we could use SUM(....
Here're a few variants, for fun :)
With your original:
=BYROW(
    A2:B4,
    LAMBDA(a,
        TEXTJOIN(
            ",",
            TRUE,
            SEQUENCE(
                1,
                SUM(
                    MONTH(CHOOSECOLS(a, 2)) -
                        MONTH(CHOOSECOLS(a, 1)) + 1
                ),
                SUM(MONTH(CHOOSECOLS(a, 1))),
                1
            )
        )
    )
)

Or
=BYROW(
    MONTH(A2:B4),
    LAMBDA(a,
        LET(
            start, SUM(TAKE(a, , 1)),
            end, SUM(TAKE(a, , -1)),
            ARRAYTOTEXT(SEQUENCE(end - start + 1, , start))
        )
    )
)



The MAP function is typically more suitable for situations like this, because it can iterate through multiple columns together, eliminating the need for supplementary functions like CHOOSECOLS or INDEX.
=MAP(MONTH(A2:A4), MONTH(B2:B4), LAMBDA(ms,me, TEXTJOIN(",",, SEQUENCE(, me-ms+1, ms))))

Also, if your Start Dates and End Dates happen to span multiple years, you could modify the formula as follows:
=MAP(MONTH(A2:A4), YEAR(A2:A4), MONTH(B2:B4), YEAR(B2:B4),
   LAMBDA(ms,ys,me,ye, TEXTJOIN(",",, MONTH(DATE(ys, SEQUENCE(, me-ms+(ye-ys)*12+1, ms), 1)))))


For more information on the differences between BYROW or BYCOL and MAP, please see:

Curious behaviour of BYROW_SEQUENCE construct


Here is a version that does not use LAMBDA or SEQUENCE (but does use TEXTJOIN), which may make it compatible with more version of Excel.
It will also work across years, but resets the Month to 1 for January:
=LET(dStart, A1, dEnd, B1, yDiff,YEAR(dEnd)-YEAR(dStart),mStart,MONTH(dStart),mEnd,MONTH(dEnd)+(yDiff*12),TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,1+MOD(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,mStart):INDEX($A:$A,mEnd))-1,12)))

However, by eliminating all of the MOD parts of the code, you can keep the month as 13 for January on Month roll-over:
=LET(dStart, A1, dEnd, B1, yDiff,YEAR(dEnd)-YEAR(dStart),mStart,MONTH(dStart),mEnd,MONTH(dEnd)+(yDiff*12),TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,mStart):INDEX($A:$A,mEnd))))

